# My Website is scrolling by itself. Can´t find a solution

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my website, it is scrolling by itself after I scrolled down a certain amount. It seems that the Image gallery on my Website is controlling the automated scrolling. I can´t find any questions asked about this problem, that's why I´m asking myself.
Hope you can help me here.

Here I have the code for my Website:

````
<html lang="de" style="background-color:#f6e9d7">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <head> <title>own website</title> </head>
     <body>
    <style>
        h1 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
   
    <div style="text-align: center; height: 230px">
    <img id="top" src="C:\Users\arnot\Pictures\website mochup defaults\LOGO Versuch 4.png" width="206" height="204" alt="index.html">
    </div>
    <h1 id="PERSONAL APPEAL" style="text-align: center; font-weight: lighter; color:#333333; font-family: sans-serif; text-decoration-line: overline" font-stretch="20%">PERSONAL APPEAL</h1>
    </body>
    <body id="Body1">
        <style>
        button {
            border-style:none;
            text-decoration:none;
            background-color:#f6e9d7;
            color:#333333;
            padding:20px;
            font-size:15px;
            width:150px;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
        }
        button:hover {
            background-color:#faf3e9;
        }
        .dropdown {
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            margin-bottom:50px;
            margin-left:-4px;         
        }
        .dropdown-content {
            display:none;
            width:100%;
            background-color:#f6e9d7;
            overflow:auto;
        }
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display:block;
        }
        .dropdown-content a {
            font-size:13px;
            display:block;
            color:#333333;
            padding:10px;
            text-decoration:none;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

        }
        .dropdown-content a:hover {
        color:#333333;
        background-color:#f7ede0;
        }
        #Shop-Pfeil {
            float:right;
            display:block;
            height:15px;
        }
        .dropdown:hover #Shop-Pfeil {
            transform:rotate(90deg);
            float:right;
            display:block;
            height:15px;
        }
        #contact {
            margin-left:146px;
        }
        #about {
            margin-left:-4px;
        }
        .animate{
        animation: navmove 2s;
        }
        @keyframes navmove{
            0%{padding-left: 0px;}
            50%{padding-left: 100px;}
            100%{padding-left:0px;}
        }
        #myTopnav{
            overflow:visible;
            position:absolute;
            width: 100%;
            background-color:#f6e9d7;
            box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        }
        </style>
        <body id="Body1">
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
          <button href="#home" id="home"class="active">Home</button>
          <div class="dropdown"href="#shop" id="shop"><button>Shop<img class="Pfeil" id="Shop-Pfeil" src="C:\Users\arnot\Pictures\WebsiteImages\Pfeil3.png" ></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#Men">Men</a>
            <a href="#Woman">Woman</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button href="#contact" id="contact">Contact</button>
          <button href="#about" id="about">About</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            var element = document.getElementById("myTopnav");            
            setInterval(checkscrolldown, 1)
            function checkscrolldown() {
                    var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
                    if(scrollTop > 250) {
                        element.classList.add("animate");
                        function pauseanimation() {
                                element.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
                        }
                        setTimeout( pauseanimation, 1000);    
                    };
                    if(scrollTop > 290) {
                        element.style.position = "fixed";
                        element.style.marginTop = "-290px";
                    }
            };
            setInterval(checkscrollup, 1)
            function checkscrollup() {
                var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
                if(element.style.animationPlayState == "paused" && scrollTop < 250) {
                    element.style.animationPlayState = "running"; 
                    setTimeout(function() {element.classList.remove("animate")}, 2000);
                }
                if(scrollTop < 290) {
                    element.style.position = "";
                    element.style.marginTop = "0px";
                }
            }
        </script>
        </body>
    </body>
    <body id="Body2">
        <style>
    *{
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }
    #Gallery{
        margin-top:79px;
        width:100%;
        height:500px;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: -2;
    }
    #Gallery ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display:none;
    }
    #Img1{
        background-color:green;
        animation:move 12s infinite;
    }
    #Img2{
        background-color:blue;
    }
    #Img3{
        background-color:red;
    }
    .img{
        height:800px;
        width:auto;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:50px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    @keyframes move {
        0%{margin-top:0px;}
        18%{margin-top:0px;}
        36%{margin-top:-800px;}
        50%{margin-top:-800px;}
        72%{margin-top:-1600px;}
        90%{margin-top:-1600px;}
        100%{margin-top:0px;}
    }
        </style>
        <body id="Body">
            <div id="Gallery">
                <div id="Img1" class="img">Image 1</div>
                <div id="Img2" class="img">Image 2</div>
                <div id="Img3" class="img">Image 3</div>
            </div>
        </body>
           <script>
               
           </script>
    </body>
    <body id="Body3">
        <style>
            #stretchWebsite{
                height:2000px;
                position: absolute;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="stretchWebsite"><button>HELLO THERE</button></div>
    </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: SO is not a free debugging service. What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? It should be easy to find the problem - especially when the only JS in the example constantly uses a variable named `scrollTop`.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code, but can't replicate that *" it is scrolling by itself"*. One glaring issue however is that you have *multiple* `<body>` tags. (?!)

Comment: The document can only have a single `body` element.

Comment: Having several different blocks of `<style>` also makes it quite confusing to keep track of what's going on.

Comment: Rather format this as a (embedded) snippet which reproduces the problem, then you'll receive more positive responses.

Comment: Thx, for the comments! What I probably forgot to mention, is that I'm a  newbie to programming in a whole. So sorry for the messed up code. I'm going to edit my question to your comments later. (Because I'm sitting in school right now ; ) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution. I put the Image div´s into a second div, which is the image_slider, and then gave the image_slider the animation

before:

```
<style>
#Img1{
    background-color:green;
    animation:gallery_animation 12s infinite;
}
@keyframes gallery_animation {
    0%{margin-top:0px;}
    18%{margin-top:0px;}
    36%{margin-top:-800px;}
    50%{margin-top:-800px;}
    72%{margin-top:-1600px;
    90%{margin-top:-1600px;}
    100%{margin-top:0px;}
}
</style>
<div id="Gallery">
    <div id="Img1" class="img">Image 1</div>
    <div id="Img2" class="img">Image 2</div>
    <div id="Img3" class="img">Image 3</div>
</div>`
```

after:

```
<style>
#Img_slider{
    animation:gallery_animation 12s infinite;
}
#Img1{
    background-color:green; 
}
@keyframes gallery_animation {
    0%{margin-top:0px;}
    18%{margin-top:0px;}
    36%{margin-top:-800px;}
    50%{margin-top:-800px;}
    72%{margin-top:-1600px;
    90%{margin-top:-1600px;}
    100%{margin-top:0px;}
}
</style>
<div id="Gallery">
    <div id="Img_slider">
        <div id="Img1" class="img">Image 1</div>
        <div id="Img2" class="img">Image 2</div>
        <div id="Img3" class="img">Image 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Even if the response wasn´t what I expected, thx for your comments. Hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Cheers!